# Strange stacked range() loop behavior python

Tags: python

```
(x,y) = 10,10  
for x in range(x-1,x+2):
      for y in range(y-1,y+2):
             print(x,y)
```

My results... The Y value seems to be increasing each loop it should be 9,10,11 every time.

```
9 9
9 10
9 11
10 10
10 11
10 12
11 11
11 12
11 13
```

I have no idea whats causing this. How can I get the desired effect?

Comment: You're trying to use the same variable name for two different things in the same scope.

Comment: The `for` loop changes `y` on every iteration, use a different variable name for the loop.

Comment: You can use `for y in y-1, y+1, y:` (unless you need increasing order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
(x,y) = 10,10
for X in range(x-1,x+2):
      for Y in range(y-1,y+2):
             print(X,Y)
```

The behaviour has to do with you re-assigning the y variable within your loop. Changing the variables assigned at for: to anything else has given me the behaviour you want:

```
9 9
9 10
9 11
10 9
10 10
10 11
11 9
11 10
11 11
```